# How to load a functions file to use its functions at my view or controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a file called `functions.php` this file contain many functions like the following

```
function name(){
  .......
}

function name2($arg){
  .......
}

function name3($par, $par2){
  .......
}

Etc.
```

That file is not a class, but contain many functions in one place.

**My questions**

1. Where can I place this file to use it from any view file or
   controller file like a global file.
2. Then, how to include any function from functions.php file at any view or controller file .

Comment: You should look in the helper section, that's exactly what helpers are for

Comment: What @Damien Pirsy is the way to go, however as Codeigniter is just a collection of PHP scripts, you can also include it in a file that always get's loaded like the config file.

Comment: I did not added my question here only after what I reviewed the user guide of codeigniter, and also I searched on the web to find anything help me, but I still don't understand how to can I do that

Comment: @Ayman Safadi: Your post really helped me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need function to be accessible through your view, you should use a customise helper:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Otherwise if you need to create a function that accessible on controller it better to create your own library:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html